# Case insensitive search in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I know this question is already been asked by many other people. Many of the solutions were suggesting to use Regular expression. I want to know is there any other ways because using regular expression slows down the query result?

For example, If I have a student table in SQL like

```
id name
 1 vicky
```

Since `SQL` is case insensitive `SELECT NAME FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME="vicky"` or `SELECT NAME FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME="VICKY"` or `SELECT NAME FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME="Vicky"` would return same result.

Whereas in mongodb if I have a student document like:

```
{
    _id:ObjectId("something"),
    name:"Vicky"
}
```

db.student.find({name:"vicky"}) will return no result.

Comment: "Since SQL is case insensitive" - wrong. This is not a property of SQL (the query language). Case sensitivity during searches is controlled by collation. Here's some info for mysql, for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Default collation is often case-insensitive, though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use `$regex`

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    $regex: "Vicky",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XFvsSDMGtRQ)

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I don't want to use regex. Is there any better approach than regex?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it fast with a text index, or much slower with lower-case without index (as a regex alternative).

**Text idex**
you can create a text index on the `name` field and `$search` on it
like

```js
db.yourcoll.createIndex( { yourfield: "text" } )
db.yourcoll.find( { $text: { $search: "vicky", $caseSensitive: false} } )

*false is the default so you dont really need it
```

**Lower case**
if you dont have an index on that field you can lowercase first and then compare.

```js
var lower_case_variable= "Vicky".toLowerCase();

aggregate(
[ {
  "$match" : {
    "$expr" : {
      "$eq" : [ {
        "$toLower" : "$name"
      }, lower_case_variable ]
    }
  }
} ]
)
```